# Datatables "footerCallback" function not displaying results in footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable, callback

I am try to get a sum of each column and display the result in the footer. I'm using ["footerCallback"](https://datatables.net/reference/option/footerCallback) function that Datatables provides. However it is not displaying anything in the footer

Datatables explains

> "Note that if the table does not have a tfoot element, this callback
>   will not be fired."

So I've added tfoot to the table so the callback will be fired

```
<table id="monthlytable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">  
<thead></thead><tfoot></tfoot></table>
```

**Callback funtion:**

```
"footerCallback": function ( tfoot, data, start, end, display ) {
var api = this.api(), data;

// Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
var intVal = function ( i ) {
return typeof i === 'string' ?
    i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
    typeof i === 'number' ?
    i : 0;
};

// Total over all pages
total = api
  .column( 3 )
  .data()
  .reduce( function (a, b) {
        return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
    }, 0 );

// Update footer
var numFormat = $.fn.dataTable.render.number( '\,', '.', 2, '£' ).display;
    $( api.column( 3 ).footer() ).html(numFormat(total));
}
```

I've tried using `"headerCallback"` with the same code as above (altered to display in the header) and it works perfectly fine.

Is there a reason why headerCallback works but not footerCallback?

Answer (score 4):

Add this:

```
buttons: [{ extend: 'print',
            footer: true }]
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem was the footer wasn't found.

I had to add the footer using `$("#monthlytable").append('<tfoot><th></th></tfoot>');`

You need to ensure the amount of `<th>` tags within the `<tfoot>` match the number of table headings your table has (This also needs to include hidden columns). So 5 table headings means 5 `<th>` tags, such as:
 `$("#monthlytable").append('<tfoot><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th></tfoot>');`

You also need to put `$("#monthlytable").append('<tfoot><th></th></tfoot>');` above where you initialise data tables.For example:

```
$("#monthlytable").append('<tfoot><th></th></tfoot>');
var table = $('#monthlytable').DataTable({
// datatable elements 
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me! I updated your answer a little as at first it didn't work, I had 6 headings in my table so I was adding 6 columns within the footer but I was getting a JavaScript error, I then realised that you have to add a column even for the hidden columns within the datatable.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Below code worked for me
//Bootstrap table 
//Below scripts required
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
$('#divID').html('<table id="tableID"><tr><th>head</th></tr><thead></thead><tbody><tr><td>some data</td</tr><tfoot><tr id="foot"></tr><tfoot></tbody></table>');

var table = $('#tableID').DataTable( {
                    "dom": '<"top"if>t<"bottom"><"clear">',
                    "bSort": false,
                    "paging": false,
                    "bFilter": false,
                "footerCallback": function(row, data, start, end, display) {
                  var api = this.api();
                 var rcnt=0;
                  api.columns('.sum', {
                    page: 'current'
                  }).every(function() {
                    var sum = this
                      .data()
                      .reduce(function(a, b) {
                        var x = parseFloat(a) || 0;
                        var y = parseFloat(b) || 0;
                        return x + y;
                      }, 0);
                    console.log(sum); //alert(sum);

                    if(rcnt==0){
                        $("#foot").append('<td style="background:#a1eaed;color:black; text-align: center;">Total</td>');
                    }else{
                        $("#foot").append('<td style="background:#a1eaed;color:black; text-align: center;">'+sum+'</td>');
                    }
                    rcnt++;
                    //$(this.footer()).html(sum);
                  });
                }
            } );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
                          var api = this.api();
                          nb_cols = api.columns().nodes().length;
                          var j = 2;
                          while(j < nb_cols){
                            var pageTotal = api
                                  .column( j, { page: 'current'} )
                                  .data()
                                  .reduce( function (a, b) {
                                      return Number(Number(a) + Number(b)).toFixed(2);
                                  }, 0 );
                              // Update footer
                              $( api.column( j ).footer() ).html(pageTotal);
                            j++;
                          }
                        },
```

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer please