# Datatables “footerCallback” function not displaying result in one column footer

Tags: datatables

I have a [JSfiddle with a datatables](https://jsfiddle.net/setbon/0pwku3af/)  where in order to get the last column (col #3 as they start count at 0) to sum up the numbers I included per [SO answer Datatables “footerCallback” function not displaying results in footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41983639/datatables-footercallback-function-not-displaying-results-in-footer) but it does not do anything.

```
$("#example").append('<tfoot><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th></tfoot>');
```

Does anyone see why it does not display ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were using wrong index (`5` instead of `3`) and one of the rows had non-numeric `Tokyo` instead of the salary.

See [updated example](https://jsfiddle.net/0pwku3af/5/) for code and demonstration.